# make a list of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to make a list of `data.frame`

```
l <- list()
l['one'] <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20)
```

but, I get this message

```
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
In l["one"] <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20) :
  número de items para para sustituir no es un múltiplo de la longitud del reemplazo
```

PD: sorry, but I get the message in spanish.

how I can create list of data frames ?

or, what structure is useful to group a set of data.frame with a identifier ?

Comment: @MamounBenghezal yes, thanks, you can add you comment as a answer?

Comment: If you have several data sets in your environment just use `mget` and `ls` combination.

Comment: If it's the same dataframe consider `replicate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the code:

```
l <- list()
l[['one']] <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20)
```

As you've written it, the single `[` is trying to allocate to a (sub) list rather than an element of the list.